# Parsing all contents from an XML file while retaining file structure (C#)

Tags: c#, xml

This should be an easy one

Lets say I have the following XML file structure

```
<my:statusReport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2005-09-22T20:42:56" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003">
<my:reportDate/>
<my:projectName/>
<my:preparedBy/>
<my:emailAddress/>
<my:managerName/>
<my:departmentName/>
<my:summary/>
<my:individualStatusItems>
    <my:individualStatusItem>
        <my:teamMemberName/>
        <my:teamMemberStatus/>
    </my:individualStatusItem>
</my:individualStatusItems>
<my:workItems>
    <my:workItem>
        <my:workItemName/>
        <my:workItemOwner/>
        <my:workItemDueDate/>
        <my:workItemStatus>0.00</my:workItemStatus>
    </my:workItem>
</my:workItems>
<my:openIssues>
    <my:openIssue>
        <my:issueName/>
        <my:issueOwner/>
        <my:issueDetails/>
    </my:openIssue>
</my:openIssues>
<my:notes>
    <my:notesDetails/>
</my:notes>
<my:signatureSection/>
<my:signatures1>
    <my:signatures2/>
</my:signatures1>
<xd:SchemaInfo LocalName="statusReport" NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2005-09-22T20:42:56">
    <xd:Namespaces>
        <xd:Namespace LocalName="statusReport" NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2005-09-22T20:42:56"/>
    </xd:Namespaces>
</xd:SchemaInfo>
```

I want to parse the entire XML file, and return a text file that does the following.

## 1. Removes as much XML formatting as possible (tags, namespaces, ect.)

## 2. retains the indented file structure

So this xml text file would return a text file that looked like this

```
reportDate
projectName
preparedBy
emailAddress
managerName
Summary
individualStatusItems 
  myindividualStatusItems
    teamMemberName
    teamMemberStatus
workItems
  workItem
    WorkItemName
    WorkItemOwner
```

What's the best tool to take with this one?

My implementation is based on this code

```
        XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlNode));
    while (xReader.Read())
    {
        switch (xReader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                listBox1.Items.Add("<" + xReader.Name + ">");
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                listBox1.Items.Add(xReader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                listBox1.Items.Add("");
                break;
        }
    }
```

However I can't get this to play well with nested structures, it only seems to work correctly with fields that are nested one level deep. It also doesn't do any namespace management, I introduced a "hacky" parser that finds the namespace at the start then parses it out of fields on its own.

I've read about alot of different approaches to take with this (XMLDoc, LINQ, XLSN), but I'm not sure what the pros/cons of each of them are.

Comment: Is it possible to simply run a regex like ```<.*>``` and delete all the matches? Wouldn't work if the xml file isn't already correctly indented but might be a good hack for it!

Comment: jdweng, good way of retaining the context of information while making it presentable. JamJar00, what do you mean by correctly indented? Also keep in mind that I need to handle the namespace tags too, the regex is a good starting point though

Comment: what will be printed in this case <my:workItemStatus>0.00</my:workItemStatus>   , workItemStatus=0.00 ?

Comment: That's exactly it jason